# getting all tweets of a twitter user, rate limit problem

Tags: twitter, rate-limiting

I've been trying to get all tweets of a some public(unlocked) twitter user.
I'm using the REST API:
[http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=andy_murray&count=200&page=1'](http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=andy_murray&count=200&page=1%27)

While going over the 16 pages (page param) it allows, thus getting 3200 tweets which is ok.
BUT then I discovered the rate limit for such calls is 150 per hour(!!!), meaning like less than 10 user queries in an hour (16 pages each). (350  are allowed if u authenticate, still very low number)

Any ideas on how to solve this? the streaming\search APIs don't seem appropriate(?), and there are some web services out there that do seem to have this data.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either queue up the requests and make them as the rate limit allows or you can make authenticated requests as multiple users. Each users has 350 requests/hour.

Comment: if I'll queue up the results it'll take me forever. (~10 users per hour, 240 per day...). I think the requests are authenticated per user, but the rate limit still applies according to IP. 
"so switching between multiple clients on the same IP offers no rate limit advantage" http://dev.twitter.com/pages/rate_limiting_faq#measurement

Comment: Authenticated limits are per user so multiple clients share the same 350/hour for a single user but multiple users on a single client all have separate rate limits. `Multiple user accounts in a Twitter client each have their own user rate limit but share the unauthenticated requests`

Comment: I'm not trying to build a twitter client. just a web service, which needs to fetch someones tweets history, not necessarily authenticated. all these requests will happen from the same IP (my server's IP), so even if i have numerous dummy users, they'll still be limited by this 350. correct me if I'm wrong. and Thanks.

Comment: It doesn't matter if it is a client or a web server. They act the same way. Each users will have their own pool 350 requests/hour.

Answer (score 2):

One approach would be to use the [streaming API](https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/reference/post/statuses/filter) (or perhaps the more specific [user streams](https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/userstreams), if that's better suited to your application) to start collecting all tweets as they occur from your target user(s) without having to bother with the traditional rate limits, and then use the REST API to backfill those users' historical tweets.

Granted, you only have 350 authenticated requests per hour, but if you run your harvester around the clock, that's still 1,680,000 tweets per day (350 requests/hour * 24 hours/day * 200 tweets/request).

So, for example, if you decided to pull 1,000 tweets per user per day (5 API calls @ 200 tweets per call), you could run through 1,680 user timelines per day (70 timelines per hour). Then, on the next day, begin where you left off by harvesting the next 1,000 tweets using the oldest status ID per user as the `max_id` parameter in your [statuses/user_timeline](http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/statuses/user_timeline) request.

The streaming API will keep you abreast of any new statuses your target users tweet, and the REST API calls will pretty quickly, in about four days, start running into Twitter's  fetch limit for those users' historical tweets.  After that, you can add additional users to fetch going forward from the streaming endpoint by adding them to the `follow` list, and you can stop fetching historical tweets for those users that have maxed out, and start fetching a new target group's tweets.

Answer (score 0):

The Search API would seem to be appropriate for your needs, since you can search on screen name.  The Search API rate limit is higher than the REST API rate limit.

Comment: Unfortunately, the search API seems to be only returning four days of results at the time of this writing.  When I hit the search endpoint with http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=from:andy_murray I'm only geting four tweets out of 871.